# Swift subclass calling super.init with parameters

Tags: swift, constructor, sprite-kit

I am trying to design a subclass of a SKShapeNode that takes on a specific width and height and only takes a position in it's initializer. Basically I want a class that makes identical boxes but allows me to initialize them with different starting positions.

When I tried to implement this I am getting an error that tells me `Must Call a designated initializer of the superclass 'SKShapeNode'`
I do not understnad how what I implemented does not called a designated initializer. Am I not allowed to set a general predetermined initializer for the subclass to call in the super?

When I attempt to make this a convenience initializer, like the message suggests, the self tag has no initializer properties to use. Honestly, what I have coded is exactly what I want to happen, I just need someone to help me make it do this thing.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SKShapeNode doesn't define a designated initializer, so it inherits SKNode's, which is `init()`. Your class *does* define a designated initializer: `init` and (unintentionally) `init(coder:)`. By making a non-convenience initializer, you disabled initializer inheritance and made it impossible to use the convenience initializers of your superclass.

Instead, you want to just chain a new convenience init to SKShapeNode's convenience init. To do that, get rid of the "coder" init, and mark your init `convenience`. Then it can chain to other inherited convenience inits by calling `self.init(...)`:

```
class DigitObject: SKShapeNode {
     convenience init(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) {
        self.init(rect: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: CGFloat(9*3), height: CGFloat(9*5)))
    }
}
```

For more on the rules, see [Initializer Delegation for Class Types](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html#ID216)
. For more on why it works this way, see [Why can’t we call superclass convenience initializer from subclass?](https://forums.swift.org/t/why-cant-we-call-superclass-convenience-initializer-from-subclass/13515/15) And for a little fun about why Swift cares so much about this, you can watch [James Dempsey](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ajlESsRXqmM) sing about how less-strict rules burned us in Objective-C.